Probability of obtaining different tens digits and different units digit by choosing 5 different integers from between 20 and 69, inclusive.
Select $5$ distinct integers uniformly at random between $20$ and $69$ inclusively.  What is the probability that your selection has $5$ distinct leading digits and also $5$ distinct digits in the units place?  Thus $\{20, 31, 42, 53, 64\}$ is a good selection but $\{20,31, 42, 53, 60\}$ would not be since $0$ occurs twice as a units place.  And $\{20, 31, 42, 53, 54\}$ would fail since $5$ occurs twice as a leading digit.
There is a problem in my book that asks the problem:

Suppose 5 different integers are randomly chosen from between 20 and 69, inclusive. What is the probability that they each have a different tens digit?
So we have the probability:

$$\frac{10^5}{50 \choose 5}.$$
I want to extend the question to ask:

Suppose 5 different integers are randomly chosen from between 20 and 69, inclusive. What is the probability that they each have a different tens digit and a different units digit?

If we want each choice to have different unit digits as well then surely the answer is
$$\frac{10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6}{50 \choose 5}?$$
To be clear I mean selecting 22 and 32 is not counted because they have the same unit digit.

I don't understand the question.  Please give an example of a successful selection and an example of a failed selection.

I am struggling to put it into words. I want to choose five numbers from the range [20,69] such that each of the five numbers not only have different tens digit, but also have different units digits, For example {21,32,46,67,59} would count but {22,32,46,67,59} does not count.

Ok, I think that's clear, but then I can't follow your "simpler" calculation. To get $5$ different tens places, the first choice can be anything, the second must be one of the $40$ that have a different digit in that place, so $\frac {40}{49}$, the third has probability $\frac {30}{48}$ and so on.

Hint for the harder version:  There are only $5$ possible tens places, but $10$ possible units places.  Pick the $5$ units places that will be chosen (how many ways?)  Match these to the tens places (how many ways?). That counts the good selections.

Ah, sorry.  Now I understand your calculation in the simpler case.  Yes, I agree with that value.

Your calculation is correct, here is another way to see it:
Of course there are $\binom {50}5$ ways to choose without restrictions.  Let's count the good choices.
There are exactly $5$ possible first digits, so we need to choose one of each, no options there.  There are $\binom {10}5$ ways to choose the five possible second digits.  Note that each occurs equally often so the choices are equi-probable.  Given such a choice, there are $5!$ ways to match the first and second digits.  Thus there are $5!\times \binom {10}5$ good choices, making the answer $$\frac {5!\times \binom {10}5}{\binom {50}5}\approx .0142725$$

This is equivalent to my answer. Right? better reasoned however :)

Yes, it is equivalent, though I find my count easier to follow (and easier to generalize) I'll edit to make it clear that I agree with your result.
